# Problem In Google Colab With Single Perceptron Logic Gates

Tags: python, perceptron

I am trying to create some simple logic gates, like AND, OR, etc., using a single perceptron. When I use the following code to create an AND gate on Google Colab:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

# AND logic gate data and labels
data=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
labels=[0, 0, 0, 1]

classifier=Perceptron(max_iter=40)
classifier.fit(data, labels)
print(classifier.score(data, labels))

x_values=np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_values=np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

point_grid=list(product(x_values, y_values))
distances=classifier.decision_function(point_grid)
abs_distances=[abs(pt) for pt in distances]

distances_matrix=np.reshape(abs_distances, (100, 100))
heatmap=plt.pcolormesh(x_values, y_values, distances_matrix)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

this is the output: [Output in Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztDZO.png)

The picture shows the decision boundary, but it is the wrong decision boundary for an AND gate.

If I use the same code in another juptyer notebook, like Kaggle, the decision boundary is correct, as shown here: [Output in Kaggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h14f.png).

Is there a problem with my code? Or just a problem with Google Colab?